# Error al guardar un producto en mi base de datos en el jsp

Tags: java, html, base-de-datos, jsp

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el siguiente problema, cuando ejecuto mi carrito de compras en jsp al darle en crear nuevo producto me retorna un falso donde deberia ser un verdadero, la conexion da bien, en modeloproductos cuando agrego manualmente el producto tambien lo ingresa bien, el problema es en producto nuevo y no se cual seria

```
package Servlet;

import Controlador.ControladorProductos;
import include.Producto;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

public class ProductoNuevo extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        FileItemFactory file_factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload sfu = new ServletFileUpload(file_factory);
        
        ArrayList<String> campos = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> imgs = new ArrayList<>();
        
        try{
            List items = sfu.parseRequest(request);
            for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) items.get(i);
                if(!item.isFormField()){
                    File archivo = new File("C:\\Users\\MILKA\\Desktop\\U\\CARRITO EN WORKBEANS\\TutorialCarrito\\web\\img\\productos\\"+item.getName());
                    item.write(archivo);
                    imgs.add("img/productos/"+item.getName());
                
                } else{
                        campos.add(item.getString());
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
        
        Producto p = new Producto(0, campos.get(0), campos.get(1), Float.parseFloat(campos.get(2)), campos.get(3), campos.get(4), campos.get(5), Integer.parseInt(campos.get(6)), campos.get(7), imgs.get(0), imgs.get(1), imgs.get(2), imgs.get(3), imgs.get(4));
        ControladorProductos cp = new ControladorProductos();
        response.getWriter().println(cp.crearProducto(p));
    }

}
```

Ahi dejo el codigo

Esta es mi clase modeloproducto
Al intentar insertar en esa clase si me funciona correctamente

```
import include.Producto;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class ModeloProductos extends Conexion {

    public boolean crear_producto(Producto p){
        
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        boolean flag = false;
        try {
            String sql = "call insertProducto(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            pst = getConexion().prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, p.getNombre());
            pst.setString(2, p.getDescripcion());
            pst.setFloat(3, p.getPrecio());
            pst.setString(4, p.getCategoria());
            pst.setString(5, p.getDetalles());
            pst.setString(6, p.getReviews());
            pst.setInt(7, p.getSize());
            pst.setString(8, p.getColor());
            pst.setString(9, p.getImg1());
            pst.setString(10, p.getImg2());
            pst.setString(11, p.getImg3());
            pst.setString(12, p.getImg4());
            pst.setString(13, p.getImg5());
            
            if(pst.executeUpdate() == 1){
                flag = true;
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally{
            try {
                if(getConexion() != null) getConexion().close();
                if(pst != null) pst.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
}
```

Insertando los datos ahi, se crea en la base de datos y si me retorna un true

Comment: Hola no se ve el codigo, agregalo como texto por favor

Comment: El código va en la pregunta, por favor eliminalo de la zona de respuestas, edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que haga falta; de paso por ffavor no redactes en mayúscula sostenida pues equivale a gritar

Comment: Jorgesys ahi lo he editado, espero puedas ayudarme

Comment: Prueba evitando el 0

Comment: Hay muchas cosas que pueden estar fallando. ¿No tienes un log con alguna excepción o algo por el estilo?

Comment: Esa parte final tiene excepcion, y la de conexion tambien, pero  la conexion si funciona